# Is Subtable possible in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a Quiz project. It has 3 tables:

- Easy
- Medium
- Hard

How to add sections to each tables like:

- Technical
- Verbal
- Logical

Whether I have to create 3 tables(diferent sections) for each 3 tables(easy,medium & hard)?

Is there a thing like `Subtable in MySQL`?

Any suggestions.. I am clueless actually..

On googling I had `seen subtables in Datagridviews & JSF`.. Is it present in MySQL & PHP?

I am working on `PHP`..

Comment: Feels to me you need to learn how to normalise tables...

Comment: any links plz @ShiguriAnemone

Answer (score 0):

USE FOREIGN KEY In your tables when storing the data

for example I'm taking Technical table

```
T_Id    Content easy_Id  med_id  hard_id
1      example   3           5       3
2      example   3           4       4
3      example   2           6       3
4      example   1           2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.. it is also possible under the `section` you have several `questions` with `diffulty`

**difficulty_table**

```
difficulty_id
description
```

**question**

```
question_id
```

**question_details**

```
question_id
section_id
difficulty_id
```

**section_table**

```
section_id
description
```

Comment: Thanks..your method is good.. but questions are imported from excel to database.. excel plainly has questions & 4 choices..

Comment: @Krishna so how will you determine the question `section` and its `difficulty`?

Comment: using dropdown box they will select section & difficulty level. and then I have to add those questions into that appropriate table

Comment: okay... so you only need to get the questions from excel file? am I correct? @Krishna

Comment: i completed that module.. I can get contents from excel and store it in mysql table.. Now i just want to know how many tables are needed?